# What type of color code is this? "^cF00F"

Tags: android, colors, hex, color-scheme

I was playing a game (Super Battle Tactics) on my android phone. In the chat window, I found out you can change the color of your text with some simple code.

Solid colors

```
^CF00F hello world
```

or gradients

```
^CF00FFFFF hello world
```

I understand how the code itself works. There's the identifier, which is ^C or ^G (color or gradient respectively). Then there's the color code F00F (red), FFFF (white), etc... And then finally, the plain text, in this case "hello world."

Now, what I don't understand is what kind of numbering this game has implemented to define colors?

Is it 4-bit hex?

If it is, how can you determine the value for blue or green?

I thought hex color values had to be represented in triplets and could only be expanded to 6-digits by doubling each digit. Like this:

```
#000 = #RGB == #000000 = #RRGGBB
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to represent colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different ways to represent colors as binary values. In his case, the examples are most likely using the RGBA color scheme, where A is the "alpha" channel which determines how transparent or opaque a color is. So `#F00F` is full intensity red and completely opaque.

Comment: Ahh! I just tested this out and you are absolutely correct! It is RGBA. I tried `F001` and the text was a nearly transparent red. Big thumbs up!